# property_copyAttributeValue(property, "T") return wired result

Tags: objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

I got wired propertyType using `property_copyAttributeValue(property, "T")`, have seen [NSHipster's article](http://nshipster.com/type-encodings/), it should be like `i`, `s`, ... but what I got is `ø¸u`, `ø¸u8`, `ø¸u8`, what may the reason of this result? here is my encoding/decoding script

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    unsigned int propertyCount;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propertyCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        char *propertyType = property_copyAttributeValue(property, "T");
        NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", property_getName(property)];
        free (propertyType);
        char *iVar = property_copyAttributeValue(property, "V");
        NSString *iVarName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", iVar];
        free(iVar);

        switch (propertyType[0]) {
            case 'i': // int
            case 's': // short
            case 'l': // long
            case 'q': // long long
            case 'I': // unsigned int
            case 'S': // unsigned short
            case 'L': // unsigned long
            case 'Q': // unsigned long long
            case 'f': // float
            case 'd': // double
            case 'B': // BOOL
                [aCoder encodeInteger:[[self valueForKey:iVarName] intValue] forKey:propertyName];
                break;
            default:
                [aCoder encodeObject:[self valueForKey:iVarName] forKey:propertyName];
        }
    }
    free(properties);
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        unsigned int propertyCount;
        objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propertyCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = properties[i];
            char *propertyType = property_copyAttributeValue(property, "T");
            NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", property_getName(property)];
            free(propertyType);
            char *iVar = property_copyAttributeValue(property, "V");
            NSString *iVarName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", iVar];
            free(iVar);

            switch (propertyType[0]) {
                case 'i': // int
                case 's': // short
                case 'l': // long
                case 'q': // long long
                case 'I': // unsigned int
                case 'S': // unsigned short
                case 'L': // unsigned long
                case 'Q': // unsigned long long
                case 'f': // float
                case 'd': // double
                case 'B': // BOOL
                    [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:propertyName]] forKey:iVarName];
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"propertyType:%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propertyType]);
                    [self setValue:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:propertyName] forKey:iVarName];
            }
        }
        free(properties);
    }
    return self;
}
```

---

**update**: found the reason: referencing a freed variable.

Comment: You're `free()`'ing propertyType, then trying to dereference it.  There's bound to be garbage.

Comment: yes, that's the reason, thanks @CodaFi